Branchlessly map one list of integers to another
I have a list of integers, which are: 28525 30068 25975 26740 29286 24947 30067. Using a single mathematical and logical expression (the faster it computes the better), I need to convert them to the list 0 1 2 3 4 5 6. I can not use a lookup table or any known hashing as it's too slow, the expression also needs to be in C.
I tried to minimize the amount of information the numbers carry while staying distinguishable by bruteforcing the second component in expression number & x. The smallest number I found this way that kept all the results different from each other was 1031, which gave me this: 1029 1028 1031 4 6 3 1027. I suppose I could add an another logical operation to narrow it down even further, however, I don't think this is the most efficient approach. Do you have any ideas on how to approach this?
By the way, I'm not sure whether I added the right tags, feel free to fix them if you think they are not suitable.
Update: I tried using remainder operator, which with bruteforcing game me: number % 14 = 7 10 5 0 12 13 9, which is much better, but still requires a couple more steps.

convert them to the list 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 Based on what, exactly?  Because a simple int result[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ); meets your requirement.

I need an expression that produces 0 for 28525, 1 for 30068 and so on up to 6

You are looking for a perfect hash function. There are Stack Overflow questions and answers about this. gperf is software for generating perfect hash functions.

Is there a windows build? Their page is not really obvious

Can you explain why "I can not use a lookup table [...] as it's too slow". A LUT is unbeatably fast. It's not space efficient, but if you know anything about the range of integers to expect you can make improvements.

@HeathRaftery I made it up

0x16532400 >> (x * 0xed >> 8 & 0x1c) & 0x7 will do the job. I do not expect it is optimal.

For only 7 values it might still be better to do a series of comparisons as they can be done in parallel by the superscalar CPU. But using SIMD would be even better as you can do 8 int16_t comparisons in a single SSE instruction or 16/32 in AVX/AVX-512 respectively

@phuclv do I need to use assembly to achive this?

@yurich obviously now, you should almost never use assembly nowadays. For things that C can't do you'll just use intrinsics instead. But many compilers already has the capability to vectorize that operation as long as you set the correct compile option: https://godbolt.org/z/157fxYse1

@HeathRaftery: I'm not so sure about "unbeatably fast".  If your LUT is excessively large and randomly accessed, then almost all accesses will miss cache, costing at least tens to hundreds of clock cycles.  (And if it's really large then it might be swapped out, and reading it from disk is a lot slower still.) If there's a fairly simple arithmetic algorithm that will work, it could very well be a lot faster than the LUT.

@NateEldredge interesting! I knew a superlative would get me in trouble. Okay, unbeatably fast once you've primed the cache? Maybe I should just relax the "unbeatable" bit...

@HeathRaftery: Priming the cache doesn't help if the table is much larger than the cache.

x * 0x3160du >> 16 & 7.
Found by brute force.

If you are on a recent x86 (Haswell or later, as this requires BMI2, and #include <immintrin.h>), you can do some bit manipulation as follows:

Find 3 bits that distinguish every input from one another and extract them: 0x1402

Encode the numbers 0 to 7 in a uint32_t, 4 bits at a time, using the indexes obtained from step 1: 0x61472053u

Extract the bits from step 2 using the index from step 1
_bextr_u32( 0x61472053u, _pext_u32( x, 0x1402) << 2, 3 )



Not sure if this is faster than the multiplication method or not, but it's probably a bit less brute force.

Based on your requirement, there are two ways of accomplishing your requirement in constant time.
The first way is by creating an array the size of the largest expected interger and just assigning the values to the array so you can map one value to another.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LIST_SIZE 7
int main() {
    int inputs[LIST_SIZE] = {28525, 30068, 25975, 26740, 29286, 24947, 30067};
    int mapper[30069] = {};
    mapper[28525] = 0;
    mapper[30068] = 1;
    mapper[25975] = 2;
    mapper[26740] = 3;
    mapper[29286] = 4;
    mapper[24947] = 5;
    mapper[30067] = 6;
    int results[LIST_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        results[i] = mapper[inputs[i]];
    }

    // Display results
    for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d ", results[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

This will always return a in constant time.
The next way is to go through the array in constant time.
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIST_SIZE 7

int mapper(int input){
    static int checker[] = {28525 ,30068 ,25975 ,26740 ,29286 ,24947 ,30067};
    static int length = sizeof(checker) / sizeof(checker[0]);
    int output = -1;

    // Don't return early to make it constant time.
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(checker[i] == input) output = i;
    }
    return output;
}

int main() {
    int numbers[LIST_SIZE] = {28525, 30068, 25975, 26740, 29286, 24947, 30067};
    int results[LIST_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        results[i] = mapper(numbers[i]);
    }

    // Display results
    for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d ", results[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}


Re "In constant time", The lookup is O(1), but the setup is O(MAX(N))

using int for a value that's smaller than a short would be wasteful. You're also utilizing cache inefficiently by using a huge array of 30069 elements while actually only 30069 - 28525 + 1 or even smaller is enough. This is far from efficient

the second solution would be nice when the compiler can autovectorize: https://godbolt.org/z/157fxYse1

@ikegami But with this little data, the worst case will still finish much quicker than a hash equation so who cares about "Big O"... Also "Big O" doesn't know about cache-friendliness. Brute force table look-up is very cache-friendly.

@Lundin, Re "the worst case will still finish much quicker than a hash equation so who cares about "Big O"...", I'm not the one who brought it up.

@ikegami You are correct but that issue can be fixed using #embed to speed up setup. You are absolutely correct that I should have used short since I only need to map between 0 and 7.

I came up with this expression:
(0x2C070010003 >> (n % 14 * 3) & 7)
, which is certainly not optimal.

Now the next question is why you believe division/modulo to be faster than iterating through an array of 7 integers... You don't have anywhere near the amount of data to beat a brute force table look-up.

This is a very flawed assumption. This still has the &7 aka %8 modulo operation, so it's still two modulo operations. , But worse, aA "modulo constant power of two" operation is almost instant (just set top bits to zero), so %14 is way more expensive. This answer is a major pessimization.

I was wrong about efficiency of my answer, I removed my claim as the answer did not perform better at benchmarks.
